# What is the best practice to translate variable resistor 500k to infinity to logic levels?

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, sensor, potentiometer, logic-level

I have a custom sensor that gives me resistance in the range of 500 kΩ to infinity, I want the 500 kΩ - 1.5 MΩ values to be perceive as a High input in my STM32 controller.
Assuming Vin = 3 V and the controller logic VIH (min) is 0.7 Vin and VIL (max) is 0.3 Vin.

[image]

My initial thought was using a voltage divider with a pulldown resistor but it means that the value of the pulldown resistor will be around 3 MΩ which could cause unreliable floating state and make my readings susceptible for noise (right?).

[image]

So I thought about using an opamp as a buffer to the voltage divider and feeding it's output to the MCU.

I was wondering if it's a good practice to do it that way? If someone could think of a better solution (in simplicity and reliability)?

Comment: What's the input impedance of the STM32 input pin? Alternatively, what's the leakage current in or out from the input pin? Normally this does not matter, but at 1 Mohm range, it could. Your buffer would negate it nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply the leakage current is between 1uA -10uA

Comment: 10 uA would dominate at 1 Megaohm and 3 V. You need a buffer as in your second example. Choose a good one with high input impedance and rail-to-rail on both input and output which is unity stable. LM741 is about as bad as it gets.

Comment: Thank you for validating my concerns! your help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Between VIL and VIH, the state of the digital input is undefined. Are you using an ADC input? Or shouldn't you better use a comparator?

Comment: No I thought about connecting to the some GPIO pin because I want it to raise interrupt when logic high value is detected. I didn't thought about using a comparator but now that you mentioned it, it sounds better and more reliable handling the undefined area. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How you do this depends on how far the sensor is from the "receiver" (the STM32), since any cabling in between will pick up noise currents and voltages which could be significant compared to the currents being measured. You can fight this noise with differential signalling, or locate the active amplification/processing locally to the sensor, with a much stronger signal being transmitted over any distance.

The latter idea would be to use a comparator (or op-amp, in a pinch), located *very* close to the sensor, and use three paths (two for power, one for the signal) to attach this remote sensor unit to to the receiver:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0XeCM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 and R3 set the switching threshold at about 600mV, which means the comparator output will switch when sensor resistance is about 7MΩ.

R4 provides a little positive feedback, for hysteresis of about 50mV. This means that the transition from low to high is about 50mV different from the threshold for transition from high to low, providing some noise immunity, and preventing oscillating transitions near the threshold.

Even if the sensor and its paraphernalia are very close to the receiver, I would still recommend this setup, because of the hysteresis. I would also recommend that you take a look at the [74HC1G14](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G14.pdf) and [74HC1G132](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc74vhc1g132-d.pdf) devices, which are logic gates with input hysteresis, and would have similar behaviour:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7SLLJ.png)</sup>

If for some reason you can't put all that circuitry near the sensor, then you'll probably need to transmit the signal as a differential voltage, which can be "received" and converted to single ended. For best common-mode noise rejection, and sufficiently high input impedance, use an instrumentation amplifier arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxUGae.png)</sup>

Using the component values shown, the ground-referenced potential at OUT is the same as the difference in potentials across the sensor. It can be then be converted to a digital signal using either of the above techniques to implement hysteresis.

R1 and R2, in combination with the sensor Rs, provide a balanced impedance differential voltage, between A and B. Any noise from the environment will be induced equally upon both nodes, and since the amplifier performs \$V_A - V_B\$, that noise is cancelled.

It is possible to find the above setup integrated into a single IC, such as the [INA126](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina126.pdf), but you'll have to hunt for one that can operate with a single-ended supply, and that can be configured for unity gain.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This answer is so detailed! It is much appreciated thank 